# SAPUI5 Table Get Clicked row data of a multi select enabled table

Tags: sapui5

I have sapui5 table with selection mode **Multi Select**.
I can get selected row data  on a Button click event which is in the page.

And also I need to  click on a row and get the data of the clicked row.
For this I've used `ItemPress`  event.

But I'm unable to get the clicked row data inside the `ItemPress` Event

This is how I attach the evet

```
oView.byId("table1").getTable().attachItemPress(this.handleItemPress, this);
```

The Table

```
    <Table id="table1" growing="true" growingThreshold="10" mode="MultiSelect">
                            <columns>
                                <Column id="TICKET_ID" hAlign="Begin" vAlign="Top" styleClass="iconCol">
                                    <customData>
                                        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "TICKET_ID", "columnIndex":"0", "leadingProperty": "TICKET_ID"}'/>
                                    </customData>
                                    <Text text="{@i18n&gt;Ticket}"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column id="NUMBER" hAlign="Begin">
                                    <customData>
                                        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "NUMBER", "maxLength": "40","columnIndex":"1", "leadingProperty": "NUMBER"}'/>
                                    </customData>
                                    <Text text="{@i18n&gt;NUMBER}"/>
                                </Column>

    </columns>
    <items>
                                <ColumnListItem type="Active">

                                    <cells>
                                        <Text text="{TICKET_ID}"/>
                                        <Text text="{NUMBER}"/>
</cells>
</ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

Item Press Event

```
handleItemPress: function(oEvent) {
        var rowobject = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().getObject();
    },
```

This gives an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a way to access data

```
oEvent.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext().getObject();
```

Comment: Correct. Although I'd suggest `getParameter("listItem")` instead of `gerParameters().listItem`.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a multiple select enabling table, then you should have an OK button. User will select items and press OK. And you can collect selected item with something similar to this:

```
onOKPressed: function(oControlEvent) {
            this.aTokens = oControlEvent.getParameter("tokens");
            this.theTokenInput.setTokens(this.aTokens);

            ...
        },
```